# Client Only and Tokens?

Tags: getstream-io

to access/write to a feed from the browser / Javascript, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878589/url-signature-missing-or-invalid-getstream) says that you have to

1. Generate a token on the server (using API key+secret),
2. Provide that token to the client (just render it somewhere)
3. Use the token from in JS when accessing the feed

My problem now is that I basically have no server side. My app uses [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), so everything is running on the client and I have no way of creating those tokens (my app is served through Firebase, and I guess all it does is serve the html files).

With the polymer/firebase setup, can I still use getstream.io somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any interaction with Firebase directly, so you'd still need some piece of middleware to handle API calls and generating these tokens.

It's an interesting idea, though. I'll add a TODO item to look into Firebase interactivity via a plugin in the future.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and for putting it on the agenda! Any chance I can use the REST API meanwhile to generate those tokens and then use the JS client for everything else?

Comment: @RandomApp only for development: 1. go to https://jwt.io/ 2. paste your api secret in the secret input field 3. paste {"resource": "*", "action": "*", "feed_id": "*"} in the payload text area. The token on the left will allow you to read/write on all feeds for you app.

Comment: Thanks the pointer! Small correction: The payload on the right has to be {"resource": "*", "action": "*", "feed_id": "*"}   (all values  *), then it works!

Comment: Is there a solution now ?

I have the exact same configuration : iPhone application with no server. Only Firebase

Comment: @CedricSoubrie unknown, you would have to contact Stream support directly for this, I haven't worked there in quite a while.